# Meteor publish: secret field of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have the following collection with an array of subdocument:

```
{
_id: 
players: [
 {
 _id: 1
 answer
 score:
 }, 
 {
 _id: 2
 answer:
 score:
 }]
}
```

I want to perform a publish function in order that it excludes the field answer of the other player. I.e player 1 should have on his local minimongo this doc:

```
{
_id: 
players: [
 {
 _id: 1
 answer
 score:
 }, 
 {
 _id: 2
 score:
 }]
}
```

I tried something like this:

```
Meteor.publish('game', function (id) {
return Game.find({_id: id}, {players.player_id: 0});
 });
```

But I don't know how to only remove the field answer for the specific player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate working with arrays like this in MongoDB. Personally I would use another collection GamePlayers with a document for each player in each game e.g.

```
Game ({ _id: g1 })

GamePlayers ({ _id: 0, gameId: g1, playerId: p1, answer: x, score: 0 });
GamePlayers ({ _id: 1, gameId: g1, playerId: p2, answer: y, score: 5 });
```

This would make things a lot easier.

But to actually answer your question here is a way to do it. I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do it but again I struggle using arrays in MongoDB so I can't think of it.

Since meteor publishes are effectively observeChanges functions we can do this:

note: this assumes that the _id of each player in the players array is equal to the user's Meteor.userId(), if it's not then you will need to provide the playerId as another argument to the publish along with gameId and change as appropriate.

I also assume your Games collection is called "games" 
`Games = new Meteor.Collection("games")`

```
Meteor.publish('game', function(gameId) {
  var self = this;

  var handle = Games.find(gameId).observeChanges({
    added: function(id, fields) {
      self.added("games", id, removeSecretPlayerInfo(fields, self.userId));
    },
    changed: function(id, fields) {
      self.changed("games", id, removeSecretPlayerInfo(fields, self.userId));
    },
    removed: function(id) {
      self.removed("games", id);
    }
  });

  self.ready();

  self.onStop(function() {
    handle.stop();
  });
});

//this function takes all the fields that would be sent to the client,
//goes through the player array and if the player's id _id is not equal to
//the id of the user making the subscription we remove the answer from the array
//before sending it to them
var removeSecretPlayerInfo = function(fields, playerId) {
  if (fields.players) {
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.players.length; i++) {
      if (fields.players[i]._id !== playerId)
        delete fields.players[i].answer;
    }
  }
  return fields;
}
```

Comment: I works. Thanks. And I agree that working with array is a bit painful, but in terms of data model, it looks more pretty.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use quotations when querying a subfield. Also note that the second parameter to find is on `options` object that should have a property `fields`.

```
return Game.find({_id: id}, {fields: {'players.answer': 0}});
```